# yii2 изменить путь до стилей yii2-debug

Tags: yii2

Когда убираю из url название папки web, пропадают стили для debug панели. Как можно изменить пути до стилей?

htaccess в корне:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(web)
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php
```

в папки web

```
RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

web config

```
'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'baseUrl' => ''
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
         ]
]
```

Если открыть debug в отдельном окне и посмотреть код страницы пути до файлов выглядят так *имя_сайта/assets/db3f1a27/css/bootstrap.css* нужно изменить на *имя_сайта/web/assets/db3f1a27/css/bootstrap.css*

Comment: Доброе утро. А как Вы убираете "web"? Что пишется в консоли браузера?

Comment: Я понимаю, что через .htaccess, но как именно, что содержится в нём? Какой шаблон yii2 используется? Где располагаются .htaccess? Что в консоли браузера? Что в конфигурации yii2-приложения? Дополните свой вопрос!

Comment: @slo_nik Убираю через .htaccess. В консоли ничего не пишется. Путь до фалов стилей debug'ера выглядит так имя_сайта/assets/db3f1a27/css/bootstrap.css нужно изменить на имя_сайта/web/assets/db3f1a27/css/bootstrap.css

Comment: Напишите всё это в вопрос, в комментарии невозможно читать.

Comment: @slo_nik пр шаблон не понял, что вы имеете ввиду

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Будем считать, что Вы используете basic шаблон yii2 потому, что Вы так и не ответили на этот вопрос.Так же не написали, какая структура у Вашего проекта. Опять же, будем считать, что она стандартная.
Положите .htaccess такого содержания в корень проекта

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteEngine on
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^.*$ web/index.php

</IfModule>
```

В директории "web" остаётся прежний

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Теперь, в файле config/web.php сделайте следующее:

```
use \yii\web\Request;
$baseUrl = str_replace('/web', '', (new Request)->getBaseUrl());
return [
  'components' => [
     'request' => [
       'baseUrl' => $baseUrl,
   ],
  ],
];
```

Это даст Вам возможность копировать файл конфигурации в разные свои проекты не заботясь о названии директории, в которой будет находиться проект.
А в urlManager напишите первое, главное правило

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
              '' => 'site/index'
        ],
    ],
```

Тогда при переходе по адресу **localhost/mysite** у Вас должна будет открыться главная страница Вашего проекта, без "web" в адресной строке.